# The local minimizer of a function on a discrete domain

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, coercive

Consider a corecive function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a minimization problem  on $h$: Minimize $h(x)$, with $x\in \{(x_1,x_2\ldots,x_n):x_i\in\{-1,0,1\}\}$.

How can we determine the number of local but not global minimizers of the function $h$? There exists a global minimimum by virtue of coercivity in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But, does there exist a minimum in the above domain? How should we proceed? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: what do you consider local?

Comment: @LinAlg I mean a extreme point that is not extreme point for the full domain of the function

Comment: Could you give an example of a local minimum that is not global? If you take $h(x)=x$, $x=-1$ is the global minimizer, but do you consider it a local minimum?

Comment: @LinAlg all global minimizers are local isnt it?

Comment: @LinAlg sorry, I did not get you, yes $x=-1$ is a local minimum for $h(x)=x$

Comment: why is $x=-1$ a local minimum? I don't see that looking at a plot of $h(x)=x$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @LinAlg but it is nevertheless a minimum in the restricted domain right?

Comment: Why is $x=1$ not a local minimum? I cannot find an $x$ with a smaller objective value in an $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $x$ for $\varepsilon<1$ within the restricted domain.